# Can I enable Alt key shortcut navigation of explorer window menus in Windows 11?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, windows-explorer, windows-11

I made heavy use of the Alt key navigation of explorer menus in Windows 10. Did Microsoft just kill this very helpful feature for no apparent reason, or is there some way to re-enable it?

Further clarification: in Windows 10, if you press the Alt key with an explorer window focused, you'll see letters pop up under the various menu options that you can type to navigate through the menus with the keyboard. This seems to be missing in Windows 11 for some reason. So, for example, now I can't seem to find a way to quickly change sorting of folders/files in an explorer window using the keyboard.

Comment: Windows 11 is very different (especially the menus and Windows Explorer) and what you want is not natively available. You would have to look at the third party Start Replacement apps and see if they offer the Explorer enhancements. I also checked Windows insider (a version or 2 ahead of Production)

Answer (score 0):

F10 opens menu bar, then press enter to open top nav item, then arrow down to sub menu item, then hit enter. E.g. F10 opens top menu with "New" highit, press enter to see list, arrow down to 'folder' the enter to make new folder. Awkward, I know, but keeps you on the keyboard.